Pearson's Chi-squared test: How does the test statistic follow $\chi^2$ distribution?
I am trying to understand how the test statistic in Pearson´s chi-squared test follows approximately the $\chi^2$ distribution.
So, we have $n$ observations from $k$ classes, where each class has the observation number $x_i$. The null hypothesis is that the observations follow a categorical distribution where $i$.th class has the probability of $p_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_i=1$.
We build the following quantity: $X^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\dfrac{(x_i - np_i)^2}{np_i}$. When $n$ is large enough, we expect approximately $X^2$ to follow the $\chi^2$ distribution. I wanted to understand how we came to this conclusion. The sum of the independent, standard normal variables $Z_1, Z_2, \dots Z_k$ follow a $\chi^2$ distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom. I can see that the observation terms $x_i$ individually follow a Binomial distribution, where $x_i \sim Binomial(p_i,n)$. When $n$ is sufficiently enough, $x_i$ is well approximated with a Normal distribution with $\mu=np_i$ and $\sigma^2=np_i(1-p_i)$. So we assume $x_i \sim N(np_i,np_i(1-p_i))$. Then we need to show each of the terms in the summation $X^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\dfrac{(x_i - np_i)^2}{np_i}$ should be a standard normal, approximately. If we had $(\dfrac{x_i - np_i}{\sqrt{np_i(1-p_i)}})^2=\dfrac{(x_i - np_i)^2}{np_i(1-p_i)}$ for each term, they would follow a standard normal distribution. However, our actual test statistic lacks division by $(1-p_i)$. How can $X^2$ then follow a $\chi^2$ distribution, when the terms lack the division by $(1-p_i)$ and such that they are not standard normal distributions? Are we assuming that $p_i$ is usually close to zero such that $(1-p_i)$ is close to $1$ and can be ignored? What am I missing here?

You need to pay attention to the degrees of freedom!  Under special conditions, the distribution of $X^2$ is approximated by a $\chi^2$ distribution with $k-1$ d.f., not $k$ d.f.

@Ufuk the deviations from expected are negatively correlated under H0.

Also related is Why does chi-square testing use the expected count as the variance?

Let $\mathbf V_n$ follows (singular) multinomial distribution. Then $\mathsf E[\mathbf V_n]=n\mathbf p, ~~\mathsf{Var}[\mathbf V_n]=n\left(\mathrm D(\mathbf p) - \mathbf p\mathbf p^\top\right)=:n\Sigma, $ ($\mathrm D(\mathbf p) :=\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf p)$), the matrix in parenthesis being of rank $k-1$ as $\Sigma\mathbf 1=\mathbf 0. $
Now using Cramér-Wold device and CLT, $$\mathbf Y_n:= \sqrt n\left(\bar{\mathbf V}_n-\mathbf p\right)\overset{\mathrm d}{\to}\mathtt N(\mathbf 0,\Sigma),$$ or $\mathbf Y_n^\top \Sigma^{-}\mathbf Y_n\overset{\mathrm d}{\to} \chi^2_{k-1}, $ owing to the fact that  the sum of the deviations between observed proportions
and corresponding probabilities is zero, reflected as $\mathbf Y_n^\top\mathbf 1=0
. $
It's easy to check a generalized inverse of $\Sigma$ is $\mathrm D(\mathbf p) ^{-1}.$ Using this, the above quadratic form $\mathbf Y_n^\top \Sigma^{-}\mathbf Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(V_{ni}-np_i)^2}{np_i}\overset{\mathrm d}{\to} \chi^2_{k-1}.$
--
Reference:
A Course in the Large
Sample Theory of
Statistical Inference, William Jackson Hall, David Oakes, CRC, $2024, $ sec. $9.2.$

Thank you for the explanation. I missed the part where $\mathbf Y_n^\top \Sigma^{-1}\mathbf Y_n\overset{\mathrm d}{\to} \chi^2_{k-1} $ how do we know that $\mathbf Y_n^\top \Sigma^{-1}\mathbf Y_n$ will approach to chi-squared distribution?

Ok, Got it, I found it here: https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mvn-chi2.html

Suppose the elements from a theoretical population are divided into $k$ disjoint categories and the probability that an individual falls in the $i^{th}$ category is $p_i, \;i=1,\ldots, k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^kp_i=1.$
Now, a random sample of size $n$ is drawn from that population and it is found that $f_i$ units in the sample belong to the $i^{th}$ category, where $i = 1,\ldots,k.$ Hence, the observed frequency (OF) in the $i^{th}$ class is $f_i$ and the expected frequency (EF) is $np_i.$ It is clear that $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i=n.$
The $\chi^2$ test statistic is defined as
\begin{align}\chi^2&=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\left(OF_i-EF_i\right)^2}{EF_i}&=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\left(f_i-np_i\right)^2}{np_i}.\end{align}
$f_i\sim \mathrm{multinomial} (n,p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k)$, since the probabilities are different for each category and $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i=n.$
Then,
\begin{align}P\left(f_i\in i^{th} \;category\right)=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^k f_i!}\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{f_i}.\end{align}
If the sample size $n$ is sufficiently large enough, i.e. $f_i$'s are not very small, we can use Stirling's approximation to get the following:
\begin{align}P\left(f_i\in i^{th} \;category\right)&\approx \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} n^n \exp\left(-n\right)}{\prod_{i=1}^k \left(\sqrt{2\pi f_i} f_i^{f_i} \exp\left(-f_i\right)\right)}\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{f_i}\\&
=\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\right)^{1-k}\prod_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{np_i}{f_i}\right)^{f_i+0.5}\left(\sqrt{n}\right)^{1-k}\left(\prod_{i=1}^k p_i\right)^{-0.5}\\
&=\mathcal{C}\prod_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{np_i}{f_i}\right)^{f_i+0.5}, 
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{C}$ is the constant with the rest of the terms.
Let, $P=P\left(f_i\in i^{th} \;category\right)\approx \mathcal{C}\prod_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{np_i}{f_i}\right)^{f_i+0.5}.$
Hence, $\ln P-\ln \mathcal{C}\approx \sum_{i=1}^k \left(f_i+0.5\right)\ln \left(\frac{np_i}{f_i}\right).$
Let us define, $e_i=np_i$ and $x_i=\frac{f_i-np_i}{\sqrt{np_i}}.$ Therefore, $f_i=e_i+x_i\sqrt{e_i}.$
\begin{align}\ln P-\ln \mathcal{C}&\approx -\sum_{i=1}^k \left(e_i+x_i\sqrt{e_i}+0.5\right)\ln \left(1+\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{e_i}}\right)\\&
\approx -\sum_{i=1}^k \left(e_i+x_i\sqrt{e_i}+0.5\right)\left(\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{e_i}}-\frac{x_i^2}{2{e_i}}+\frac{x_i^3}{3{e_i^{1.5}}}-\cdots\right)\\&
=-\sum_{i=1}^k \left(x_i\sqrt{e_i}+x_i^2+\frac{x_i}{2\sqrt{e_i}}-\frac{x_i^2}{2}-\frac{x_i^3}{2\sqrt{e_i}}-\frac{x_i^2}{4e_i}+\cdots\right)\\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^k \left(x_i\sqrt{e_i}+\frac{x_i^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e_i}}\right)\right),\end{align}
where $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e_i}}\right)$ involves higher powers of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e_i}}.$
If $e_i$'s are large, the $x_i$'s are small compared to $\sqrt{e_i}$'s and the expansion $\ln\left(1+\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{e_i}}\right)$ is valid.
$$\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\sqrt{e_i}=\sum_{i=1}^k \left(f_i-e_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^k f_i-\sum_{i=1}^k e_i=0$$ since $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i=\sum_{i=1}^k e_i=n.$
Thus, $\ln P-\ln \mathcal{C}\approx -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e_i}}\right).$
If $n$ is large and therefore $e_i=np_i$ is large, $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e_i}}\right)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty.$
Hence, $P\approx \mathcal{C}\exp\left({-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}{2}}\right)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty.$
Thus, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ independently and identically follows a standard normal distribution.
Now, let us consider the orthogonal transformation, $\underline{Y}=\mathbb{A}\underline{X}$, where $\mathbb{A}$ is an $\perp$ matrix with its last row as $\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_1},...\sqrt{p_k}\right).$
Thus, $\underline{Y}'\underline{Y}=\underline{X}'\underline{X}.$
$\sum_{i=1}^k y_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2$ and $y_k=\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\sqrt{np_i}=\sum_{i=1}^k \left(f_i-np_i\right)=0.$
Hence, $$\chi^2 =\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} y_i^2.$$
Under the orthogonal transformation, $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_k$ also independently and identically follows a standard normal distribution.
So, the $\chi^2$ being the sum of $k-1$ independently and identically standard normal distributed variables, follows a $\chi^2$ distribution with $k-1$ degrees of freedom.

Formatting tips, whenever you use $$ $$, include the punctuation mark within it. Use the {align} environment whenever there are multiple steps in your derivation. And use \left( \right) for full coverage of the parentheses

Appreciate you worked on your formatting. I have edited further re the formatting. Check that.
